# Using gem pundit, why author of a post cannot edit or delete it in Ruby on Rails 4.0.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, pundit

I am newbie to rails using `ruby` 1.9.3 and `rails` 4.0.2 and `pundit` 0.2.1

The post model consists of:

```
belongs_to :user
```

The user model is generated by using `devise` gem (and does **not** have `has_many :posts`)

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
```

I did `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate` and my `schema.rb` now has `user_id` in `posts` table.

Then I followed this [blog](http://www.ruby-on-rails-outsourcing.com/articles/2012/11/23/getting-started-with-pundit/) for using gem `pundit`

I have exactly the same code shown in that blog. Furthermore I added this to my post controller actions:

```
def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post].permit(:title, :text))
  authorize @post
    if @post.save
        redirect_to @post
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  authorize @post
end

def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  authorize @post 
    if @post.update(params[:post].permit(:title, :text))
        redirect_to @post
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  authorize @post
    @post.destroy

    redirect_to posts_path
end
```

I am not getting any kind of error(`NoMethodError` like I got when I used `cancan` gem).

But **no user**, not even the author of post, is able to edit and destroy his post.

It simply shows  `Couldn't find post`. (which is alert message from `rescue_from` `Pundit::NotAuthorizedError`)

I tried changing logic in `PostPolicy` `owned` method which is there in blog post but it didn't work.

With these models and schema, how can I achieve this simple authorization (only author of post should be able to edit and delete his post) without using any gems?

I tried other similar questions over here but none worked for me.

As my authorization is working, now i am struggling customising `views` specifically `edit` and `destroy` links for posts `index.html.erb`

Only Author of a post must be shown edit and delete links for his posts.

I followed [elabs/pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) for customising views by using policy method.

Here is my code for `post_policy.rb`

```
class PostPolicy < Struct.new(:user, :post)
  def owned
    post.user_id == user.id
  end

  def create?
    post.user_id = user.id
    new?
  end

  def new?
    true
  end

  def update?
   edit?
  end

  def edit?
    owned
  end

  def destroy?
    owned
  end
end
```

And this is the code in post `index.html.erb`

```
<% if policy(Post).edit? %>
  <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></td>
<% end %>

<% if policy(Post).destroy? %>
  <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', post_path(post), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
<% end %>
```

According to pundit documentation on [elabs/pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) it says we can get instance of the `policy` through the `policy` method in both the `view` and `controller`.

For me it gives `NoMethodError in Posts#index` and `undefined method user_id for <Class:0x22d64d8>`

I have user_id field in post.
I think i need to pass @post with policy for getting that user_id.
I tried other ways but no success.

Comment: It would be useful to see your application controller code and your post policy.

Also, your controller here doesn't show how you're assigning the post to the user when it's created so check your database and see if any of the posts you have created have a user_id assigned to them. This may well be your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Uri for editing the question.

Thanks a ton Andy for guiding me properly. As you said the `user_id` was nil for new post created. I just assigned current user's id to `post.user_id` in `create` method

```
def create?
 post.user_id = user.id
 new?
end
```

in

```
post_policy.rb
```

All my auhtorizations are now working fine.

But now I am struggling with policy method used for customising views. I have edited the question accordingly along with code.